# Getting an image from MySQL using JDBC

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I want to get image from mysql database.

Im using Jdbc library.

I only tried to upload image to **mysql database(blob)** and I want to display the retrieve image to imageview in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the same stored blob back using basic sql select query.After that you can use

```
Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob(blobIndex);
```

to get the blob as java object.
You can convert this blob to inputstream using

```
resultSet.getBinaryStream(blobIndex)
```

or byte array using

```
imageBlob.getBytes
```

Once you have the bytes array you can use

```
setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, Bytes.length));
```

to set the image in image view.